# how to make notes section in an app (already created) in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This might be hard to explain but I'm working on a project using java in android studio. I'm unsure how to start, whether to use SQL or not, etc. I literally just want a blank "page" with the ability to be able to type and possibly store the "notes" written in it? I've tried tutorials but they are making a notes app as a whole when I just want to add a notes section? I made a terribly drawn idea and my code is below that I've tried from a tutorial! Any help is appreciated!

[whiteboard drawing here lol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0EU2.png)

```
<EditText
 android:layout_width="391dp"
 android:layout_height="523dp"
 android:hint="Type here..."
 android:gravity="top"
 android:id="@+id/EditText1"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
//SAVING FILES BELOW
CS
public void Save(String fileName) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter out =
            new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(fileName, 0));
        out.write(EditText1.);
        out.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Note Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

//LOADING FILES CODE BELOW
public boolean FileExists(String fname){
  File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(fname);
  return file.exists();
}

//MAIN CODE BELOW
//YOU CAN CHANGE - COULDN'T MAKE JUST ONE SECTION
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText EditText1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Save("Note1.txt");
            }
        });

        EditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        EditText1.setText(Open("Note1.txt"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void Save(String fileName) {
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter out =
                new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(fileName, 0));
            out.write(EditText1.getText().toString());
            out.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Note saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public String Open(String fileName) {
        String content = "";
        if (FileExists(fileName)) {
            try {
                InputStream in = openFileInput(fileName);
                if ( in != null) {
                    InputStreamReader tmp = new InputStreamReader( in );
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tmp);
                    String str;
                    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        buf.append(str + "\n");
                    } in .close();
                    content = buf.toString();
                }
            } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {} catch (Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        return content;
    }

    public boolean FileExists(String fname) {
        File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(fname);
        return file.exists();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what type of data you want to store you may need to use alternate ways. [This](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) article provides a detailed overview of all the data and file storage options you have.

I guess that you want to store possibly large data, so I think that in your case, the most suitable and optimal option is to use the [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) local perstistence library.

Since you mentioned whether to use SQL, as stated in the aforementioned documentation, Room provides the following benefits

- Compile-time verification of SQL queries.
- Convenience annotations that minimize repetitive and error-prone boilerplate code.
- Streamlined database migration paths.

and as a result it is recommended that you use Room library instead of using the SQLite APIs directly.